# How to resolve "width property is deprecated, use style to define the width of the Dialog." warning

Tags: angular7, primeng

I get the following warning in angular 7 and primeng 7 even when I do not have any width properties declared.

> width property is deprecated, use style to define the width of the
>   Dialog.

Does anyone have a clue on how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Width and minWidth are deprecated.

Use the style prop to do what you want :

```
<p-dialog [style]="{width: '500px'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This assignment also works

```
<p-dialog [style.width]="'500px'"
```